# Cannot resolve GetResources(), set context for non-activity class Android

Tags: java, android

I created DBHelper.java class in my android project. In my OnCreate() method I create tables to my database, but I also want to insert rows to these tables. So I made file - script.sql, that contains my insert queries. Everything would work fine, but I cannot solve one problem - context.

This is my code I put in DBHelper class:

```
   private void executeScript()
{
    InputStream inputStream = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.script); // I get error here.
    byte[] buffer = new byte[7844];
    String queries = "";
    try {
        inputStream.read(buffer);
        queries =  new String(buffer,"UTF-8");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.toString());
    }
    for (String query : queries.split(";")) {
        Log.e("Query", query);
    }

}
```

I get error in line : this.getResources()...
I know that I can't use this, but what can I do instead?
I know this code just displays logs, but I'll add execSQL later.

Comment: Am I right in thinking you basically want this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android

Comment: I tried it but I got some errors I can't handle with. Maybe there's another way to execute my script that I don't need to use context

Comment: If you want to get a resource you generally need a Context. What are the errors you're getting when you do the above?

Comment: I tried again, I got errors because I wrote MyApplication class in current activity. This time I create new MyApplication.java class in my project and it seems to be working. I am just not sure that method like that is good solution. There has to be better solution for this. Anyways, thank you, I've been trying to solve this problem for 2 hours...

Comment: I tend to agree. You should avoid a static getter if you possible can. Ideally you want to propagate the Context down and pass it as an argument to    `void executeScript(Context context)`

Answer (score 0):

Pass the text of the script into `executeScript()`, by having the caller retrieve the `R.raw.script` resource value.

Or, pass a `Resources` into `executeScript()`, so it can call `openRawResource()`.

Or, pass a `Context` into `executeScript()`, so it can call `getResources()` on the `Context`.

Comment: TLDR: dependency injection.

Comment: I want to keep all text of the script in one file, because it will be bigger and I don't want to put all of these in code.

What do you mean pass resources into executeScript??

Can you write how would it look in my code. Thank you